# Where do folds come from on a surfboard and are they bad?

Tags: surfing

Why are there sometimes folds on the top of a surfboard and where do they come  from? Do they mean the board is in bad shape (or more exactly, is the board less usable or less effective)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are creases. They effect performance as the board will flesh (bend) more around that point. The board is much more likely to break in half at that point as well. Creases can be fixed, can be expensive for epoxy boards ($200-$300 minimum) and requires a pro to do it right. A bad fix can weaken the board further.